# How do you translate this sentence (I thought I knew something, then I realised I knew nothing) to Latin?

Tags: sentence-translation, translation-check, english-to-latin-translation, motto

I want to translate "I thought I knew something, then I realised I knew nothing" into Latin. The result I got from Google translate is this "Quod cogitavi cognovi: tunc animadvertebam nihil scirem." I am completely Latin illiterate and I would like to use this sentence as a motto for an event. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

*Putavi me scire aliquid, tum agnovi me nihil scire.*

Starting the main clause with "putavi" emphasizes the fact that this thought is now far from us; also, ending it with "aliquid" gives more importance to the fact that it's not *nothing*.

In the secondary clause I used *tum*, as in, following that - if your "then" is more like "but then", this may be substituted by *autem*.

Comment: I would use the imperfect _putabam_ rather than the perfect _putavi_: "I was in a state of thinking"

Comment: @ColinFine: I see what you mean, that construction highlights the interruption of such "state of thinking". However, for a different effect, I still abide by my explanation for the perfect; cf. the preterite of the Romance languages, e.g. Dante makes Vergil say _homo iam fui_ when he first sees him in his Inferno (actually he uses the Italian _già_ instead of _iam_, but that's the same).